# DVCS with Central Build/ automatic push to server feature?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I am looking for alternatives to [NWDI](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw72/helpdata/en/49/2fe24eb7476b1fe10000000a42189d/content.htm) (Stands for Netweaver Development Infrastructure by SAP) source control system for developing 
Java EE Applications. Primarily because:

1. NWDI is not DVCS : So developers have to be online to do just about anything.
2. User Interface: Its very difficult to use and train developers on using this system.
3. Tracking Changes/Generating Reports: Very limited support for this. 
   For example I cant find out what projects (Files within the project) have been changed in the last 2 weeks.
4. Code Review: You can do code reviews, it has a good diff utility. But thats about it, there is no way to attach code reviews to a change request.
5. Branching and Merging are extremely painful.

However the current system has a few handy features:

1. Automatic Builds: No need to write any build scripts , everything is built in. So when a new repository (we call it track)
   is created it automatically configures the build  based on the type of components (Supported by the repository) selected on creation.
   A Central Build is triggered whenever a developer commits (Activates the changes). Irrespective of the status of the build the changes are now inflicted on the entire team.
2. Automatic push to Central Test Server: While creating a repository you can define all the servers (Central test, QA, Prod). A developer can push his changes by a
   click of a button to Central Test Server. Again everything is built in and there is no need to extend any hooks like you have to do in Mercurial.

I was exploring [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) and but couldn't find anything helpful. For mercurial [Hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) can be used to do the same but I guess some customization effort is required.

Are there any cool DVCS like Mercurial which does the above 2 as well or is it something that I have to customize to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there nothing useful out of the box. I am going to try out Kiln as it appears to be easy to use and try customizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a DVCS proposing everything build-in.
The only alternative (not DVCS, but with some of DVCS characteristics in it) is [Rational Team Concert or RTC](https://jazz.net/library/LearnItem.jsp?href=content/docs/rtc1.0-capabilities/index.html) (free for up to 10 developers).

With a DVCS alone, the usual setup for CI and reviews is:

- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) (review)
- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (scheduler)

See "[Using Gerrit Git Review with Jenkins CI Server](http://vimeo.com/20084957)"

Comment: I cant find any either. I think I will try out Mercurial and Kiln to see if I can customize them.